# missing data from firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Realtime database for android app, there were some data , multiple records , but I checked it today and no data is showing up and it shows just **null**, what is wrong and how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

What can you see on the console? Does it at least show the name of the DB? If you think you lost the DB, I suggest locking the DB with the following rules:
`{ “rules”: { “.read”: false, “.write”: false } }`
This way no one will be able to get in to your DB.

After that, I highly suggest [filing a ticket to support](https://firebase.google.com/support) asking for a RTDB restore so they can get your DB back.

Comment: no db name is shown , but its childs the actual data is gone , already contacted the support , hope they can restore the data .

Comment: Alright then it was completely wiped out, I suggest investigating what could have happened, if you had open rules (instead of `false` you have `true` in the rules I shared) then most likely there was some bad actor involved, please share that with support as it may be asked.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked a few of my projects and the data in the Realtime Database shows up fine in the Firebase console fine for those, so it doesn't seem to be an outage.

The first thing I'd recommend is to try again on a different browser and/or different network, just to rule out any issues with connectivity or browser extensions.

Given the `null`, it may be that the data was actually deleted. If that is the case and it is unexpected, it might be worth checking if your code can mistakenly delete the data - or if your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) allow deleting data that they shouldn't allow.